# Make QueryAABB touch in the center of a body to respond

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I am allowing the user to drag their fingers to select bodies. The bodies are then added to a array list to be removed later.

The problem is, i would like the users finger to have to cross the middle of the body before it is added to the array instead of being able to touch any where in the bodies.

Right now when the user finger even crosses a corner of the body it is added to the array, it wont it to only be added if the user finger crosses the middle of the body or the middle inside of the body.

Any ideas? My code is below.

I am using Circle shapes for he bodies.

```
@Override
public boolean touchDragged(int x, int y, int pointer) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    vecTemp.set(x, y, 0);
    camera.unproject(vecTemp);

    hitBody = null;

    world.QueryAABB(callback, vecTemp.x - 0.1f, vecTemp.y - 0.1f, vecTemp.x + 0.1f, vecTemp.y + 0.1f);

    if(!selectedObjects.contains(hitBody, true) && hitBody != null){     
        selectedObjects.add(hitBody);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'middle'? You probably want to use the TestPoint function of the fixture to check if the touch is inside it. The Box2D testbed should have an example that you can look at for dragging bodies around.

Comment: @iforce2d Basically right now when the user drags their finger across a body and they may just touch the egde of another body and it adds it to the array to be removed. I dont want this to happen, instead i would like for the user to have to cross touch the middle of the body for it to be selected not the edges.